# Simplify this simple expression?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

So the expression is  $-(1/3)(1/2)^{3/2} + 1/3 - (1/3)(1/\sqrt{2})^3$.

The answer in my book is $1/3(1 - 1/\sqrt{2})$. But that simplifies to $1/3 - 1/3\sqrt{2}$.  How come it isn't $1/3 + 2(-1/\sqrt{2})$, which is what I got.

Comment: This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: Because... you did it wrong?  How can we answer why you got the wrong answer if we don't know *how* you got the wrong answer.

Comment: Probably because you didnt add of the two terms that are essential $(\frac 12)^{\frac 32}$ properly.  $(\frac 12)^{\frac 32} = \frac 1{2\sqrt 2}$ and so $2*\frac 1{2\sqrt 2} = \frac 1{\sqrt 2}$.

Comment: Sorry I'm asking on a smartphone but got your answer thx!

Answer (score 1):

$ −\frac 13(\frac 12)^{\frac 32}+\frac 13 −\frac 13(\frac 1{\sqrt 2})^3=$

$\frac 13[-(\frac 12)^{\frac 32}+1 - (\frac 1{\sqrt 2})^3]=$

$\frac 13[-(\frac 12)^{\frac 32}+1 - (\frac 1{2})^{\frac 32}]=$

$\frac 13[1 - 2*(\frac 1{2})^{\frac 32}]=$

$\frac 13[1 - 2*(\frac 1{2})^{1+\frac 12}]=$

$\frac 13[1 - 2*(\frac 1{2})^{1}(\frac 12)^{\frac 12}]=$

$\frac 13[1- \frac 12^{\frac 12}]=$

$\frac 13 - \frac 1{3\sqrt 2}$

Comment: @N.F.Taussig I suppose fleablood should be familiar with those, given the amount of reputation he has.

Comment: Well, good for you.  I guess...

Comment: I deleted my answer since your answer is more complete.